# Flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.0 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, widget, flex4

[image: emulator display]

I tried to make a login page with an animated logo, two TextField and a button. when I ran the app and tried to put some value in the TextField then the keyboard shows up and it looks like the image I provided.
The error is: A RenderFlex overflowed by 4.0 pixels on the bottom.

Here is my code :

```
    Scaffold(
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
          inAsyncCall: _spinner,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Hero(
                    tag: 'logo',
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50),
                      child: Container(
                        height: animation.value * 50,
                        child: Image.asset("lib/images/chat.png"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Email",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        email = value;
                      },
                      
                  const Text(
                    "Password",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        Password = value;
                      },
                      
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          _spinner = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text("Registar"),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.blueAccent,
                        minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(40), // NEW
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
```

image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your ListView with SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
```